# Android device id on google analytics

Tags: android

Is there any way how to show the mobile device id on the google analytics page from which the app is  being used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can show it.You can send any value like mobile device id or any string value while calling EasyTracker.getTracker().trackView("Mobile ID"+ yourmobileid), then you can view this information on Google Analytics dashboard under Screen Views.